# How do Jewish people understand the commandment not to make or worship idols?

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, shema, aseres-hadibros

The first commandment given to Moses on the mountain is clear and unambiguous. In English it reads "I am the LORD your God, who  brought you out of Egypt, out of the land of slavery. You shall have no other gods before me."

The second commandment makes it clear that His people must not make any idols or graven images to worship.

I respectfully ask for an English interpretation of this commandment.  Forgive me for not knowing what the appropriate tags are - I am not Jewish and do not pretend to understand Hebrew.  Perhaps someone could edit the appropriate tags needed?

I ask this question in order to respond to a specific Christian denomination that has seen fit to exclude the second commandment from their teachings.

Comment: What exactly do you find ambiguous about the second commandment?

Comment: This covers it: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912359/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-One.htm

Comment: Or if it's very specifically _that_ commandment out of the 50 or so, then here ya go: https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.20.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Sefer_HaMitzvot%2C_Negative_Commandments.1.1&lang2=bi

Comment: @Harel13 - I do not find anything ambiguous about the second commandment, but it has come to my attention that it has been removed from a significantly large Christian denomination. I am trying to establish the original and authentic Hebrew wording as translated into English in order to make a robust defense of that specific command.

Comment: Please don't waste your time trying to argue with the fundamentals of a entire religious denomination. You're not going to change anyone's mind.

Comment: If you want a full treatment on the Jewish view, Maimonides lays it out very clearly, but it is long: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1.1?lang=en

Comment: Appreciate everyone's helpfulness and links.  I realise I'm not going to change anyone's mind, but I do want to understand the issues that have been raised so that I can respond to anyone who asks me why I hold a particular view - and why I disagree with another.  It's not about trying to convert anyone or wining an argument.  It's about being clear on what the word of G-d says.